# How to get top output with swift 3 on osx (NOT iOS)

Tags: macos, swift3, macos-sierra

```
// Playground

import Foundation

let task            = Process()
task.launchPath     = "/usr/bin/top"
task.arguments      = ["-s","2"]
let pipe            = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.launch()
let data            = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
task.waitUntilExit()

print(String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
```

This code work with "/bin/ls" instead of "/usr/bin/top" and when i put others argument but like it is actualy i get nothing on playground and it crach in my xcode8 project with an "An uncaught exception was raised" and it lunch a debuger with asm.So how to get TOP output in a variable ?

Comment: For an asynchronous task like `top` you need an asynchronous method to process the output for example subscribing to the `readInBackgroundAndNotify` notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found

```
// Playground

import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let task            = Process()
task.launchPath     = "/usr/bin/top"
task.arguments      = ["-s","9"]
let pipe            = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
let outHandle       = pipe.fileHandleForReading

outHandle.readabilityHandler = { pipe in
    if let line = String(data: pipe.availableData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        // Update your view with the new text here
        print("New ouput: \(line)")
    } else {
        print("Error decoding data: \(pipe.availableData)")
    }
}

task.launch()
```